# Why is Netbeans 8 IDE very slow when font size in increased?

Tags: netbeans-8

Increasing the font of the editor (either thru the command line or the editor settings) to a large font make the editor slow and unusable on a Mac (with 8Gb). This seems to have gotten worse in version 8.

I've updated netbeans.conf as follows:
netbeans_default_options="--fontsize 14 -J-client -J-Xss128m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=256m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m  -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"

Has anyone experienced a similar problem and were you able to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not with NetBeans, but with the JDK. There's a [Java/JDK bug affecting Retina displays](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8029253), and it was only recently fixed in the Early Access JDK (8u40). Get [the latest JDK 8 EA](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and that should fix it.